# TF CuDNNLSTM minimum value is always higher than 0, even when train data was 0... Like it was shifted + 5

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Basically I've tried this code

```
np.random.seed(7)
            dataframe = read_csv('c:/data/suicides.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
            dataset = dataframe.values
            dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

                # normalize the dataset
            scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
            dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

                # split into train and test sets
            train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
            test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
            train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

            # reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
            look_back = 1
            trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
            testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

                # reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
            trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
            testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))


                            # Initialising the RNN
            #regressor = Sequential()
            model = Sequential()

            # # In[25]:


            # # Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
            model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 10, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (trainX.shape[1], 1)))
            model.add(Dropout(0.1))


            # # In[26]:


            # # Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
            model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 5, return_sequences = True))
            model.add(Dropout(0.1))


            # # In[27]:


            # # Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
            model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 4, return_sequences = True))
            model.add(Dropout(0.1))


            # # In[28]:


            # ## Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
            model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 2))
            model.add(Dropout(0.2))


            # # In[29]:


            # # Adding the output layer
            model.add(Dense(units = 1))


            # # In[30]:


            # # Compiling the RNN
            model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')


            # # In[33]:

            #     #epoch = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

            # # Fitting the RNN to the Training set
            model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = _epoch, batch_size = _batch)



            # make predictions
            trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
            testPredict = model.predict(testX)
```

Unfortunately for some reason while there are long time series of 0, it won't predict zero.

Ever. Min/max for train / test data starts with 0, but predict data always is like 5-6 for min. value.

Train/test data is from 0 - ~ 40

I've tried different settings, number of epochs, Activation, optimizer, loss but always min. value for predict data > ~ 15% of max train value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason batch > 1 in time series was generating too high minimum predictions.

Solved by modification of a batch settings + model training settings.

So if you have predictions that are > 0, then probably there is something wrong with training settings.